# SQL Composite Key

Tags: sql, database-design, constraints, primary-key

I am a SQL newbie and here is a question that I cannot find a solution yet.

Say I have tables `User` and `Partner`. I want to have a composite key for `Partner`, which is a pair of `User`'s. So I can have keys (A,B) and (B,A) where A and B are both users. I want to have that (A,B) and (B,A) refer to the same `Partner` entity. This seems to be a common problem but I could not find an answer.

Ok, more concretely,

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    ID int,
    ....
)
PRIMARY KEY (ID);

CREATE TABLE Partner
(
    User1 UserID,
    User2 UserID
    ...
)
PRIMARY KEY (User1, User2)
```

What I want is that (User1, User2) and (User2, User1) represent the same partnership.

Comment: What's a partner entity? can you illustrate by example

Comment: This looks more like a bad design! Please upadte the question and try to add the structure of the desired table.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to to make (A,B) and (B,A) considered as the same, you can take an arbitrary decision to always have A have the lower ID (*), and back it up with constraints;

```
CREATE TABLE partner (
    a INT NOT NULL,
    b INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, b),
    CHECK (a < b),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES user(id)
)
```

(*) Or the larger one - it doesn't really matter, as long as you're consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.  One is to ensure that both `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` are in the table.  You can do this using a trigger when you insert a row.

The second is to include only one of the pair -- normally as an ordered pair.

Basically, it depends on how you are going to use the table.  The first method requires twice as much storage, but it is simpler to get all the partners of a given user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that both pairs must be included in the table then just add another constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Partner ADD FOREIGN KEY (User2,User1) REFERENCES Partner (User1,User2);
```